# Append data in a specific region from one file with data from a second file in awk, bash

Tags: python, bash, awk

I have a problem and I'm wondering if anyone can help. I have two .dat files where each is composed of three columns separated by a space. I have one file that covers my whole range of data (let's call it normalstate) and a second file that contains a specific region of it in a different state (let's call it diffstate), where outside of this region the data would be the same as the normalstate. My data takes a long time to run, so rather than running the same data again across the entire range I would like to splice the diffstate data into the normalstate data if possible.

Both files are sorted by the first column and in real life run for some ~150 values in the range from -5 to +3 or so in the first column. Here I've just put a few test values for simplicity.

i.e.
file1 (normalstate):

```
1 a1 err-a1
2 a2 err-a2
4 a4 err-a4
5 a5 err-a5
6 a5 err-a6
```

file2 (diffstate):

```
2 b2 err-b2
3 b3 err-b3
5 b5 err-b5
```

And my desired output is where it creates a new file where the diffstate data is wedged in the middle of the relevant normalstate data, or equivalently where the normalstate data is appended onto the diffstate data at the start and end of the file.

So the desired output is something like:

```
1 a1 err-a1
2 b2 err-b2
3 b3 err-b3
5 b5 err-b5
6 a6 err-a6
```

Note 1: where the column 1 value =2 and =5 exist in both files, I want to keep the diffstate data but not the normalstate data.

Note 2: the normalstate data might contain values in the region where there is diffstate data that the diffstate data does not have e.g. column 1 value=4. I do not want to keep these values, since they will muck up my analysis, I only want to keep the diffstate values in this region.

Note 3: I would like the file to still be ordered by the first column.

I'm sure there's a relatively simple way of doing this, probably using awk or the join command or something. My plan is to put it into a shell script that I can copy and reuse for different data sets, I have a similar one using awk and join for checking if two files have the same data and only keeping the data that is shared by both sets, but I'm not sure how to extrapolate to this example since I'm just learning how they work. Up until now I have been doing it manually with copy and paste, but I'd like a way to do it more efficiently that's easier to keep track of. If there's a more intuitive way of doing it in Python or something that would work too. Sorry, I'm really new to this! Any help at all would be appreciated, and if you can explain your solution it would be really helpful. Thank you so much!

Comment: Why is `4 a4 err-a4` lost but not `1 a1 err-a1` and `6 a6 err-a6`?

Comment: Hi @JamesBrown - in my analysis, outside of the diffstate region the data would be equivalent to the normalstate data hence why I can keep those two, but it is not the same inside that region hence why i want to discard 4. My goal is to keep the data from normalstate specifically outside of the region where i have the diffstate data. The column 1 value=4 data is lost since it is normalstate data in the middle of the diffstate region (which is 2 to 5 here). The other two are kept since they are outside of the diffstate region, i.e. below 2 and above 5. I hope that makes sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one. I expects the files to be preordered, so if not, instead of for example `file2` use `<(sort file2)`:

```
$ awk '
NR==FNR {                                    # process diffstate
    if($1<min||min=="")                      # get range min
        min=$1
    if($1>max||max=="")                      # get range max
        max=$1
    b=b (b==""?"":ORS) $0                    # buffer the records
    next
}
{                                            # process normalstate
    if($1<min)                               # print values below range min
        print
    else if($1>=min && $1<=max && b!="") {   # skip values in range
        print b                              # instead print buffer
        b=""                                 # ensure printing buffer only once
    } else if($1>max)                        # print values above range
        print
}' file2 file1
```

Output:

```
1 a1 err-a1
2 b2 err-b2
3 b3 err-b3
5 b5 err-b5
6 a5 err-a6
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's perfect!